# Python Sklearn - Multidimensional Parameter Optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, numeric, numerical-integration

I am not too convinced by the parameter optimization classes sklearn provides, in fact `GridSearchCV` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) just loops over the parameters I pass in via `param_grid`. `RandomizedSearch` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) seems like a `we-gave-up`-approach to me.

One of my approaches was to re-use adaptive integration of a function (used in numerical mathematics): basically reduce the search-space of a parameter in every iteration until a certain error-threshold is reached. The biggest advantage of this method is that the error is also reduced in each iteration.

The problem is that certain parameter-values may be untouched if you consider the different score-values (`precision`, `roc-auc` etc.) as functions. I still got good results in one case, not so good in other cases.

What would be a good mathematical approach to optimize values more efficient than GridSearch and RandomizedSearch?